# Django apps that add content to the same page

Tags: python, django

I have written a Django website with a simple home page containing a list of the following menu items:

- Home
- Users
- Contact

I am now working on an optional Django app for this website. When installed, I would like it to add an extra menu item to the home page called "Extras".

What is the best way to achieve this sort of thing in Django?

I have considered adding something like this to my settings.py file:

```
MENU_ITEMS = [
    'Home',
    'Users',
    'Contact',
]
```

Then inside my app's __init__.py, I would do something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.MENU_ITEMS.append('Extras')
```

And the views.py file would then pass this MENU_ITEMS list to the home page template. Is this the correct approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Is there some reason you are approaching this programmatically? The simplest way would be to add an 'Extras' link to the menu in the base HTML template.

Comment: @JohnMee Wouldn't that result in a broken link if the extra Django app is not installed?

Comment: You're right. I see (now) that you're trying to build a module that can install and remove itself.  In that case you might be interested in [inspecting the installed apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.is_installed) to assist deciding what items belong in your menu - excepting that the inspection itself would be part of the install?!  I'm tempted to suggest you're in over your head.  I am.

Answer (score 0):

A tip i would give you from experience: don't mess with settings in runtime if possible, those variables are global and changing them may cause some nasty bugs. I'm not sure but with that code you may end up with something like:

```
MENU_ITEMS = [
    'Home',
    'Users',
    'Contact',
    'Extras',
    'Extras',
    'Extras',
    'Extras',
]
```

Again, I'm not sure of that but you don't need to mess with your settings to achieve your purpose.

A way more clean approach is let your view manage your view. If all you want is a menu, create a base template and put the menu there and then extend from it. If you want to add anything in the future you will need to change that piece only (You can add conditions there if you want to render some parts depending on user or something).
For more details refer to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/).

For example:

```
<div class="header navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{% endraw %}{{ cookiecutter.project_name }}{% raw %}</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>

          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'users:detail' request.user.username  %}">{% trans "My Profile" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">{% trans "Logout" %}</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">{% trans "Sign Up" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">{% trans "Log In" %}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
```

If this is defined in your base template, the pages that extend it will show it by default, overriding only the section where the block content is located. If you want to add another link to your navbar just do something like:

```
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'my_other_url' %}">My new item</a></li>
```

You define 'my_other_url' as usual in your urls.py.
This is the right approach to do what i think you are trying to do. You let the templates handle how your site looks, don't mess views (as in mvc) with your controller.

If you want to make the extra item optional you just have to send a flag or something to the template and use:

```
{% if flag %}
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'my_other_url' %}">My new item</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I could achieve this? I want the extra app to add an element to the existing home page, not create a second home page that inherits from the original one, which is what the docs describe.

Comment: You can try installing this project template: https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django. Make it work and then go to the templates/base.html. You can see they have several pages and they all have the navbar. That is the base i use for my projects. (if you don't want to install it you can just check the templates/base.html template in github)

Comment: Not sure I understand. The navbar in cookiecutter has a set of links that are defined in the base template (see https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/templates/base.html). How would another app add an extra link to this navbar?